# bashrc not activated

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bashrc

I have installed the Anaconda data science package on my Ubuntu 16.04 server. To make it work (I think this means adding Anaconda to the path), I must enter, *every time* after I log in to the server via ssh:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

I suspect that the path (which is automatically written to bashrc by the Anaconda installer) should be added to some other file.

Comment: Is your shell set to bash explicitly? Because Debian-based `bash` called as `sh` won't read `.bashrc`. Check the man page for `chsh` to see more.

Comment: I fixed this by adding `source $HOME/.bashrc` to the bash_profile.

Comment: You should answer as an answer, not a comment, even on your own question

Answer (score 2):

To make it work, add

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

in `~/.bash_profile`

**Explanation** :

There are three main files which bash sources depending on how the shell is spawned.

1. `~/.bash_profile` - sourced on **interactive login mode** that is:

   - Login at the console ( Ctrl+Alt+F1..F6)
   - Connect via ssh
2. `~/.profile` - sourced by **graphical login** that is :

   - Launching via gnome-session
3. `~/.bashrc` - sourced on **non-login interactive mode** that is:

   - Opening a terminal

Since in your case , you are connecting via ssh i.e interactive login mode  so ~/.bash_profile will be sourced automatically, so you can source your .bashrc from there.